# Android scrollable Listview of images from drawable

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, instagram, scrollable

I would like to implement a scrolable view, like in Instagram, shown below.

[image]

I need it to work exactly like in Instagram:

1. Thumbnails are stored in Drawable.
2. They are scrollable.
3. They are clickable.

I wanted to implement it with ListView. But, besides Listviews not being available in horizontal mode (at least by default), after reading posts about similar situations, got confused as to which view is suitable for this case, ListView, GridView, Gallery, ...

Really appreciate any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

GridView is ideal for this (it is basically a ListView, taking an adapter, you could define it as a single row, with multiple columns), however, currently it is OS 4.3+ only (hoping they include an implementation in the Support Library soon).

For your needs, you can and should use a HorizontalScrollView.  It is not as extensible as a ListView, but will certainly fit your particular needs (and works on all APIs - well API 3+).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html